# Object Exist But it Returns Null

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want to save  values to a table and then delete a row from another table. However its saves to table but not deleting from other table.
Console says object null but when i print text value and check in table from parse.com I'm sure there is an objectId same as text in Wish table.
This is the code which i used.

```
        @IBAction func TakeWish(sender: AnyObject) {
        var takenWish = PFObject(className: "TakenWish")
        takenWish["title"] = self.wishTitle.text
        takenWish["description"] = self.wishDesc.text
        takenWish["url"] = self.wishUrl.text
        takenWish["userName"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.username
        takenWish["takenUserName"] = self.username.text
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(wishImage.image!)
        let imageFile = PFFile(name: "image.png",data: imageData!)
        takenWish["imageFile"] = imageFile



        takenWish.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {

                // The object has been saved.
            } else {
                // There was a problem, check error.description
            }
        }
        var deleteQuery = PFQuery(className: "Wish")
        deleteQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: text! )
        deleteQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects , error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                if let objects = objects {
                    for object in objects {
                        object.deleteInBackground()

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        displayAlert("Taken", message: "Wish Has Been Taken !")

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toPro", sender: nil)
    }
```

But when i use this code separately in another button it works.

```
    var deleteQuery = PFQuery(className: "Wish")
    deleteQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: text! )
    deleteQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects , error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                    object.deleteInBackground()

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What is wrong with this code how i can fix it ?

Comment: check in first code response listener if the object exist or not

Comment: sorry but i don't understand clearly

Comment: now i checked object returns null but i print to text and then i checked that value exist in wish tables objectId . So i really don't understand why object returns null..

Comment: dude if you are still on Parse, this is the least of your worries.